# How could this possibly result in a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am doing a post-mortem on an Android app crash and my reasoning fails to explain how could the app end up in such situation.

Since this is a production app, it's obfuscated with ProGuard and I was silly enough to have lost the mapping file for the particular version of the app. However with some voodoo magic I was able to figure out from this:

```
0   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
1   at com.einpix.android.a.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
2   at com.einpix.android.d.f.a(Unknown Source)
3   at com.einpix.android.d.f.a(Unknown Source)
4   at com.einpix.android.f.g.a(Unknown Source)
5   at com.einpix.android.d.g.onLocationChanged(Unknown Source)
6   at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:290)
...
```

That the problem actually happens in the `equals(...)` method:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    private static final String TAG = "Entity";
    protected int localId;
    protected int remoteId;

    public Entity(int localId, int remoteId)
    {
        this.localId = localId;
        this.remoteId = remoteId;
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return getLocalId();
    }

    public int getLocalId()
    {
        return localId;
    }

    public int getRemoteId()
    {
        return remoteId;
    }

    public void setLocalId(int id) {
        this.localId = id;
    }

    public void setRemoteId(int id)
    {
        this.remoteId = id;
    }

    public boolean equals(Entity other)
    {
        if (other == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (App.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "equals: " + this.getClass().getCanonicalName() + " vs " + other.getClass().getCanonicalName() + " --> " + (other.getClass().getCanonicalName().equals(this.getClass().getCanonicalName()) ? "Y":"N"));
        if (!other.getClass().getCanonicalName().equals(this.getClass().getCanonicalName())) {
            return false;
        }

        if (App.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "equals-localId: " + this.getLocalId() + " vs " + other.getLocalId() + " --> " + (this.getLocalId() == other.getLocalId() ? "Y":"N"));
        if (this.getLocalId() == other.getLocalId() && this.getLocalId() > 0) {
            return true;
        }

        if (App.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "equals-remoteId: " + this.getRemoteId() + " vs " + other.getRemoteId() + " --> " + (this.getRemoteId() == other.getRemoteId() ? "Y":"N"));
        if (this.getRemoteId() == other.getRemoteId() && this.getRemoteId() > 0) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

(There is a logical sequence leading to this place and this is one of the few places in my code where `.getClass()` is actually used)

So my question is, considering that this method got invoked (thus `this` cannot by any means be null) and the first `if` check is to see if `other` is null - how could it possibly be that at some point calling `.getClass` on one of those two results in a `NullPointerException`?

P.S. `App.DEBUG` is set to `false` before releasing the app, so it's a safe assumption in this case. However I'm leaving those lines here for completeness sake.

**UPDATE**

The call to this method comes from an if-clause one level below:

```
if (currentClosest != null && !currentClosest.equals(lastClosest) && !currentClosest.equals(currentChosen))
```

`currentClosest`, `lastClosest` and `currentChosen` being instances of `public class Venue extends Entity` (or possibly null)

Apparently, in my `Venue` class I have another `equals()` method defined:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
    if (!(o instanceof Venue)) {
        return false;
    }
    Venue v = (Venue) o;
    return (this.getLocalId() == v.getLocalId() || this.getRemoteId() == v.getRemoteId());
}
```

This is silly and unnecessary, however I don't see how it could play any part in this crash case. This method does not have any calls to `.getClass()`

Comment: Where are you calling this method? Do you realize it doesn't override `Object`'s `equals`? (though `Object`'s `equal` wouldn't throw NPE if the other object is null).

Comment: It's coming from an if condition one level below: `if (currentClosest != null && !currentClosest.equals(lastClosest) && !currentClosest.equals(currentChosen))` - not sure how that is relevant though. As for overriding, I don't care - as long as I can compare 2 instances of `Entity` and be sure that they are of the same class + either local or remote ids of theirs match

Comment: `currentClosest` being an instance of `public class Venue extends Entity`, as well as `lastClosest` and `currentChosen` (either can optionally be `null`)

Comment: Make sure you don't have another `equals` method in `Venue` class that gets called instead of the one in `Entity` class.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I apparently do (see update in the question). I still fail to see how that could play any part in this. Since the NPE comes from a `.getClass()` call, I still think it's the entity's method that gets executed and triggers the exception

Comment: `public boolean equals(Object o)` is NOT overriding `public boolean equals(Entity other)` from Entity. It overrides equals function from `java.lang.Object` as Eran said. So ensure which equals function you are calling in your code.

Comment: @Fusselchen - yes, I am aware of that. And as I said - the exception comes from calling a '.getClass()` method on a null object reference, and only one of those two methods have calls to `getClass` - thus I stand my position that it is the one in `Entity` class that gets invoked and ends up with an exception. Unless you see any flaws in this logic of mine, I would kindly ask you to focus on the original question how does the exception in the Entity.equals(Entity E) can possibly occur.

Comment: Then follow the full stacktrace, there should be a line where exactly the NPE is thrown inside your function. Just for ensure it is inside the code you post, and not somewhere else, because i also don't see any Problem at the posted equals function

Comment: Just thinking out loud: Considering this call/crash came from an even handler (i.e. background thread) while the UI thread was working in a related context (though report says there was no user activity for the last ~1minute before the crash) - could this somehow be so that one of the objects/references got updated from a different thread? (My multithreading-fu is not strong at all) Should I be doing a `synchronized` on the `equals(Entity other)` ?